Clear template cache from inside of a plugin
Is there a way to clear the template cache via a plugin? I didn't find a way to only clear the template cache and keep the rest of the cache intact. As far as I know there is also no fitting CLI command. I'm currently working in Craft 4.

I've had a quick look at how this is done in Craft's own Utilities controller. I think you should be able to clear the template cache with this code:
$this->requirePermission('utility:clear-caches');

$cache = Craft::$app->getCache();
TagDependency::invalidate($cache, 'template');



As far as I know there is also no fitting CLI command

No, there is! Check out the invalidate-tags/template command.
